# Alter email that an error email is sent to for errors in a package

Tags: email, managed-package

We have a package. During the upload of the package, we specify a user to receive the emails when errors occur in the package. 
The package may deal with personal health information. Some organizations that install the package want to override the email that errors get sent to since they worry that the email could contain private health information.
Is it possible for the installer of a package to disable the emails or override the email address that the errors are sent to?

Comment: Without knowing more about what triggers the send of the email and how it is that you specify who the user is (or their email address) that receives that email, it would be impossible of any of us to answer your question. If you can put that in a custom setting that's configurable by the Admin, it would be simple for them to change it.

Comment: @crmprogdev  The user is specified in the "Notify on Apex Error" field in the package properties. I like the idea of having it in a custom setting that is public to the package user but am not sure of what I would need to override.  The emails I am talking about are the ones that are generated by SFDC on an unhandled apex error, not ones generated under the packages control (those are handled and sent to the admin of the org that installed the package).